# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException. Invalid property <blah> is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the requirement to remove all passwords and encryption keys from the source code of my project. I'm struggling to get this to work in my spring-servlet.xml file.
This worked before I tried making the change:

- the database username, encrypted password, URL and driver were defined in a file jdbc_server.properties as a classpath resource.
- the encryption/decryption key was passed on start-up as -DENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=

I want to move the jdbc_server_properties file to the filesystem and include the key in the file.

This is my last (of at least 25) attempt at getting this to work.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="standardEncryptor" />
        <property name="jdbcUsername" value="JDBC_USERNAME" />
        <property name="jdbcPassword" value="JDBC_PASSWORD" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="JDBC_URL" />
        <property name="jdbcDriver" value="JDBC_DRIVER" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///${USERPROFILE}/credentials/jdbc_server.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="standardEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbcDriver}" p:url="${jdbcUrl}"
        p:username="${jdbcUsername}" p:password="${jdbcPassword}">
</bean>
```

Using the above configuration, I get a NotWritablePropertyException exception. I've seen tons of posts on this issue but not where both the properties and encryption key are in a file on the filesystem.
When this was working and the properties were read from a file in the classpath, there were no getters/setters for jdbcUsername (or the other properties) so I don't know why it's failing in this way now.

I tried adding the getters and setters (as String) to my BaseDaoImpl class but I still get the same error so if I'm supposed to add them, I'm not sure where they go.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jdbcUsername' of bean class [org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]: Bean property 'jdbcUsername' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at ...
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the exception? You have definied in XML that a property named `jdbcUsername` must be set on the `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which it clearly doesn't have. Also adding the encryption key to the file won't work (and would be pretty louse as well, as what security would there be left, if you already have the key to decrypt next to the encrypted keys, you are basically locking your door, but are leaving the key in the lock).

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because `jdbcUsername` is not a property of  `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Please, try something like this (just remove the `jdbc*` properties from the `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` configuration, and use it directly in your `dataSource` bean):

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="standardEncryptor" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///${USERPROFILE}/credentials/jdbc_server.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="standardEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${JDBC_DRIVER}" p:url="${JDBC_URL}"
        p:username="${JDBC_USERNAME}" p:password="${JDBC_PASSWORD}">
</bean>
```

Assuming your `jdbc_server.properties` file contains the required information:

```
JDBC_USERNAME=ENC(...)
JDBC_PASSWORD=ENC(...)
JDBC_URL=ENC(...)
JDBC_DRIVER=your.jdbc.driver
```

Comment: Well now I'm getting this org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [org.jasypt.spring4.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] to required type [org.jasypt.util.text.TextEncryptor]. 
But what you suggested is a definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: I am happy hear that, great. Is that your only configuration related with jasypt? Please, can you verify that your XML configuration is the one I provided? It looks like in the `<constructor-arg ref="standardEncryptor" />` xml element you were referencing other bean.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me honest. You're right, I didn't copy correctly. But now that I have, I'm getting this:
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434)
 at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:740).
I tried just putting the key in there as <property name="password" value="real password" /> and it accepted that but still didn't seem to access the DB. I'll keeping digging Monday. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is ok Brutus ;). The problem is that the decryptor was unable to find the password required for decryption. Please, be sure to define the corresponding System property. You can try also with `passwordEnvName`. Be sure that the password provided and the algorithm used to decrypt the information is the same you used to encrypt it. Use the encrypt.sh and decrypt.sh shell scripts, or the windows equivalent cmd, to verify it. You can found these script in the `bin` folder of the jasypt distribution.

Comment: I agree that passwordEnvName is the right property name and so I changed it but I'm still getting the NPE. I'm sure the filename is correct (I tried changing the filename to file:///${USERPROFILE}/credentials/blah_server.properties and I get a FileNotFoundException). I'm using the encrypted password as when the jdbc_server.properties file was in the classpath and the same key that was passed as a start-up argument. I'll keep working at this but any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And,how are you defining the environment property? Please,can you define it as an actual environment property not a java system property? You can define it in your server startup script or even at the OS level by exporting it

Comment: The key is in the jdbc_server.properties file as ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=My_Enc_password. The requirement I have is that all of they keys, userids, and passwords must be in a file on the filesystem. The key used to be in the startup script and that's where this whole problem started.

Comment: The problem is that Jasypt is unable to read the encryption password from any file, only directly (a bad idea, of course, if you later put the information under source control) or by environment properties. If you **must** define the password in a file, why not place that file anywhere and `source` it as part of your server startup? There is no other way.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I got putting the username and password in a file outside of the classpath to work now. I'll work on your suggestion about sourcing the key.

Comment: You are welcome, thank you Brutus. Please, do not hesitate to contact me again if you need further help.